# Testing a shellcode

Tags: c, shellcode

I have this piece of code to test a shellcode but  I don't understand it so can anyone explain it to me?

Forget about the assembly shellcode, what I want to understand is the C code,

```
char shellcode[] = "...";

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{

int (*func)();

func = (int (*)()) shellcode;

(int)(*func)();

}
```

I mean everything, what are the empty `()`, please explain it as if you are explaining it to a beginner.

Comment: Since the shell code is "unimportant", I've elided it (just to be safe).

Comment: User name seems like a good way to get put on CIA and GCHQ databases. Together with the question, you can probably expect a visit from the SAS at any moment...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
int (*func)();
```

This is a declaration of a function pointer. A function pointer is essentially a variable that holds the address of a function. In this case, the type of function that `func` points to is a one that takes no arguments and returns an `int`. You can assign the address of a function to this variable like so:

```
func = foo;
```

Where `foo` is a function with the prototype `int foo();`.

Once a function has been assigned to this variable, you can call the function that `func` points to like so:

```
(*func)();
```

There is an alternate syntax (which is equivalent), which I think is more clear:

```
func();
```

So if `foo` was assigned to `func`, then both examples above would actually call the function `foo`.

You can also cast values to function pointers. In the code example

```
(int (*)())
```

is a cast to a function pointer that takes no arguments and returns an `int`. This is so the compiler won't complain about assigning what is essentially a `char*` to the function pointer `func`.

In the code you gave above, there is one last thing. After `func` is called, the result is (for some reason) cast to an `int`. As far as I can tell, this cast is totally unnecessary. So the last line

```
(int)(*func)();
```

could be replaced with

```
(*func)();
```

Answer (score 3):

`int (*func)();` is the definition of a pointer to a function with return type `int`, `func = (int (*)()) shellcode;` assigns a function pointer an address to the `shellcode[]` (assembler bytecode, the instructions your CPU executes), `(int)(*func)();` calls the function by its address (assembler instructions) with no arguments passed, because `()` is specified. For example the assembler instruction `\x90` has name `NOP` (**N** o **Op** eration) and does nothing, other assembler instructions do different things depending on the system you're executing them on.

Comment: thnx Yasir, but didn't get so well, so func = (int (*)()) shellcode , what does it do? does it take the address of shellcode and place it in func? and is the function implementation

Comment: To the question author: every function in C has the address, `func = (int (*)()) shellcode;` tells the compiler that the code of the function begins from the first byte of `shellcode[]`, but you have a function that is just the assembler code. Since every C program after compilation becomes an assembler code, this is not a problem, and calling `(int)(*func)();` should result in execution of the assembler instructions you put in `shellcode[]`.